# Running an SQL query faster

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, query-optimization, normalization, relational-database

```
   SELECT projectID, urlID, COUNT(1) AS totalClicks, projectPage,
   (SELECT COUNT(1)
     FROM   tblStatSessionRoutes, tblStatSessions
     WHERE  tblStatSessionRoutes.statSessionID = tblStatSessions.ID
     AND    tblStatSessions.projectID = tblAdClicks.projectID
     AND    (tblStatSessionRoutes.leftPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage OR
           tblStatSessionRoutes.rightPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage)) AS totalViews
   FROM   tblAdClicks
   WHERE  projectID IN (SELECT projectID FROM tblProjects WHERE userID = 5)
   GROUP  BY projectID, urlID, projectPage
   ORDER  BY CASE projectID
          WHEN 170 THEN
           1
          ELSE
           0
      END, projectID
```

This is by no means an especially complex query, but because the database is normalised to a good level, and we are dealing with a significant amount of data, this query can be quite slow for the user.

Does anyone have tips on how to improve the speed of it?  If I strategically denormalise parts of the database would this help?  Will running it in a stored proc offer significant improvements?

The way I handle the data is efficient in my code, the bottleneck really is with this query.

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres?

Comment: SQL-Server is what this is running on.  Only have v2000 which is a bit rubbish!

Comment: Also, some formatting on your query wouldn't go astray. Edit: Oh, that's better.

Comment: There are two major problems 1) The Db is **not Normalised**, but you think it is. "denormalising" the unnormalised may help, but Normalising it will help much more. Post a new question with your data model. 2) the query is badly formed, the outer query does not define a clear structure, which the Subquery can depend upon. 3) And of course IN uses a worktable, so change that to a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De-normalising your database should be a last resort since (to choose just one reason) you don't want to encourage data inconsistencies which de-normalisation will allow.

First thing is to see if you can get some clues from the query execution plan.  It could be, for example, that your sub-selects are costing too much, and would be better done first into temp tables which you then JOIN in your main query.

Also, if you see lots of table-scans, you could benefit from improved indexes.

If you haven't already, you should spend a few minutes re-formatting your query for readability. It's amazing how often the obvious optimisation will jump out at you while doing this.

Comment: +1 Says everything I was going to say.  Plonk it into Query Analyser and see the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to break up that

```
projectID IN (SELECT projectID FROM tblProjects WHERE userID = 5)
```

and use a JOIN instead:

```
 SELECT 
     projectID, urlID, COUNT(1) AS totalClicks, projectPage,
     (SELECT COUNT(1) ....) AS totalViews
 FROM
     dbo.tblAdClicks a
 INNER JOIN 
     dbo.tblProjects p ON a.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
 WHERE 
     p.UserID = 5
 GROUP BY 
     a.projectID, a.urlID, a.projectPage
 ORDER BY 
     CASE a.projectID
        WHEN 170 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END, a.projectID
```

Not sure just how much this will help - should help a bit, I hope!

Other than that, I would check if you have indices on the relevant columns, e.g. on `a.ProjectID` (to help with the JOIN), and maybe on `a.urlID` and `a.ProjectPage` (to help with the `GROUP BY`)

Answer (score 1):

If your dbms has a tool that explains its query plan, use that first. (Your first correlated subquery might be running once per row.) Than make sure every column referenced in a WHERE clause has an index.

This subquery--WHERE projectID IN (SELECT projectID FROM tblProjects WHERE userID = 5)--can surely benefit from being cut and implemented as a view. Then join to the view.

It's not unusual to treat clickstream data as a data warehouse application. If you need to go that route, I'd usually implement a separate data warehouse rather than denormalize a well-designed OLTP database.

I doubt that running it as a stored proc will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to remove the correlated subquery (the inner `(SELECT COUNT(1) ...)`). Having to join against your session routes where either the left page or the right page matches makes things a bit tricky. Something along the lines of (but I haven't tested this):

```
SELECT tblAdClicks.projectID, tblAdClicks.urlID, COUNT(1) AS totalClicks, tblAdClicks.projectPage,
       SUM(CASE WHEN leftRoute.statSessionID IS NOT NULL OR rightRoute.statSessionID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalViews
FROM tblAdClicks
     JOIN tblProjects ON tblProjects.projectID = tblAdClicks.projectID
     LEFT JOIN tblStatSessions ON tblStatSessions.projectID = tblAdClicks.projectID
     LEFT JOIN tblStatSessionRoutes leftRoute ON leftRoute.statSessionID = tblStatSessions.ID AND leftRoute.leftPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage
     LEFT JOIN tblStatSessionRoutes rightRoute ON rightRoute.statSessionID = tblStatSessions.ID AND rightRoute.rightPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage
WHERE tblProjects.userID = 5
GROUP BY tblAdClicks.projectID, tblAdClicks.urlID, tblAdClicks.projectPage
ORDER BY CASE tblAdClicks.projectID WHEN 170 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, tblAdClicks.projectID
```

If I were to add some cache tables to help this, as I indicated I'd try to reduce the two queries against tblStatSessionRoutes for both left and right page to a single query. If you know that leftPageID will never be equal to rightPageID, it should be possible to simply use a trigger to populate an additional table with the left and right views in separate rows, for example.